# Is it necessary for both the divorced parents to consent for their younger than 12 years old kid to wear face mask or get tested for COVID-19?

Tags: divorce, covid-19, children, netherlands

I guess there is some consent needed since the kid is younger that 12 years old. But is it necessary for both the parents to consent? Does the opinion of the kid also count? More specifically I would like to know if one of the parents can prevent any of the two by being against it. To be clear, I am asking for wearing a face mask and getting tested, not for vaccination.

Comment: I don't know about all English-speaking countries, but at least in the US, a "mouth guard" is worn by some athletes, such as boxers, to reduce injuries to the cheeks and teeth in case the athlete is hit in the face. The thing that is worn to reduce the spread of COVID-19 and similar diseases is called a "face mask" or just "mask".

Comment: Thank you @gerard! Edited!

Comment: I would think that the language of a divorce decree would be relevant. While I am not terribly familiar with Dutch divorce law, I would imagine that it could allocate certain decisions to either parent or both parents, and that whether the decision was of a type of decisions requiring joint decisions would depend in part on what the decree said. Some decisions clearly wouldn't: you don't need joint consent on the issue of whether the kid wears pants to the grocery store. Also consent to routine things (required school vaccinations, bandaids, aspirin) might not be "major" consent decisions.

Comment: Might not government authorities mandate masks for everyone over, say two years old?

Comment: If there is a mask law **neither** opinion matters.